# How to disable next/previous key ( from mouse ) in Electron?

Tags: javascript, navigation, electron, mouse, disable

I have an Electron application, with differents pages. Some buttons of my app make the user navigate between these pages. But the user can also navigate to the previous/next page using keys in side of mouse. How to disable these keys please ?

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX7Gm.png)

Comment: I don't know of a standard way of doing this. There is an [`app-command`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-app-command-windows-linux) event that will fire when you use the mouse buttons, but I don't believe you can cancel the event. And from some testing, it doesn't even look like the event is firing for mouse buttons. Could you add a `mousedown` handler in your page and just cancel navigations?

Comment: Thanks ! It was mouseup event not mousedown, but that worked fine cause i have the buttons pressed in the event ( 3 = previous and 4 = next ).

Comment: great to hear! I posted an official answer

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't appear to be a standard way of doing this.

There is an [`app-command`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-app-command-windows-linux) event on the `BrowserWindow` that will be triggered for [AppCommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN) related to pressing the back/forward button on the mouse.

```
mainWindow.on('app-command', (e, cmd) => {
  if (cmd === 'browser-backward' || cmd === 'browser-forward') {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Now the event isn't cancelable, but in theory, you could add a [`will-navigate`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-will-navigate) event and just cancel the subsequent navigation (or do it backwards where all navigations are canceled, except when you click your buttons).

Unfortunately, that solution doesn't seem to work, because that event isn't being triggered when the back/forward buttons are pressed presumably due to [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17134).

While that's an issue, you could intercept the `mouseup` event and cancel it for the back and forward [buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button#return_value):

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
   if (e.button === 3 || e.button === 4)
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
win.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
  this.disableMouseNavigation();
});

private disableMouseNavigation(): void {
    const disableNavigationScript = `
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
        if (event.button === 3 || event.button === 4) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
      });
    `;
   win.webContents.executeJavaScript(disableNavigationScript);
}
```